# ¿Qué significa el error -Xbootclasspath/p is no longer a supported option?

Tags: java, apache-netbeans

Soy un estudiante de grado superior en el modulo de Despliegue de Aplicaciones Web y estoy estudiando para recuperar una materia que suspendí.

En dicha materia usamos el IDE de Apache NetBeans 12.6. Mi problema es que cuando quiero compilar un proyecto JAVA en una java MainClass me sale el siguiente error:

> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
> -Xbootclasspath/p is no longer a supported option.
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
> C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.6\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
> C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.6\executor-snippets\run.xml:94: Java returned: 1
> BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

La cuestión es qué significa el error y cómo lo puedo solucionar.

Comment: Parece que el problema está en la línea de comandos. Muestra la configuración de tu proyecto para que podamos ayudarte. Deberías encontrar `-Xbootclasspath` en alguna parte.

Comment: Es más importante saber qué version de java utilizas que qué IDE. Las opciones -Xboothclasspath no son válidas a partir de java 8. Si en clase usabas java 8 y en casa tienes una versión mayor, o si te has descargado un programa de java hecho para una versión inferior a la tuya probablemente el problema sea que tienes esos flag en la configuración de inicio del IDE por eso te da error. Eso es lo que significa el error. Para solucionarlo.... quita los flag inválidos (es que de hecho es literalmente la traducción del error a español!)

Comment: Vale muchas gracias